# interpreting ancova and extracting estimated means

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, ancova

Imagine the following data:

```
ds <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,z=rep(c("A","B"),each=5))
```

the means for groups in `z` are:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(ds, "z", function(x) mean(x$y))
#  z V1
#1 A  3
#2 B  8
```

do a couple of models:

```
m1 <- glm(y ~ x , data = ds)
m2 <- glm(y ~ z , data = ds)
```

In `m1` the intercept is zero and the estimate for x is 1 as we would expect form the created data. Intercept meaning the value of `y` for `x=0`.

In `m2` the intercept is `3` and the estimate for `B` is `5`. This is because of the contrasts between the intercept with the estimate i.e. the estimate for `B` is 8. These results make sense in terms of the means of my data as calculated separately above.

so for `m1` I interpret intercept as `y where x=0` and `slope` and for `m2` as this is an anova, `intercept` as mean of first level and the rest are differences between that level and the first.

However in the following models `m3` and `m4`

```
m3 <- glm(y ~ x + z , data = ds)
m4 <- glm(y ~ x * z , data = ds)

# m3
#Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  1.123e-15  6.201e-16  1.812e+00    0.113    
#x            1.000e+00  1.720e-16  5.814e+15   <2e-16 ***
#zB          -7.628e-17  9.880e-16 -7.700e-02    0.941    

# m4
#Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  1.123e-15  8.714e-16  1.289e+00    0.245    
#x            1.000e+00  2.627e-16  3.806e+15   <2e-16 ***
#zB          -9.349e-17  2.305e-15 -4.100e-02    0.969    
#x:zB         3.130e-18  3.716e-16  8.000e-03    0.994
```

The coefficients for intercept and `x` are the same as `m1` but how do I interpret the estimate for `B` and `A` as the estimate for `B` is `-7.628e-17`.

My question is how do I interpret the categorical estimates in `m3` and from the output extract the estimated means, which I would report? and for `m4` is the slope for `x:zB`  `1.000e+00 + 3.130e-18` and for `A` `1.000e+00 - 3.130e-18`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models have a problem, you have added no error to your *y* so you get a perfect fit with your *x* variable. So let's fix this first:

```
set.seed(123)
ds <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10+rnorm(10, 0, 0.5),z=rep(c("A","B"),each=5))
m1 <- glm(y ~ x , data = ds)
m2 <- glm(y ~ z , data = ds)
m3 <- glm(y ~ x + z , data = ds)
m4 <- glm(y ~ x * z , data = ds)
summary(m1)
summary(m2)
summary(m3)
summary(m4)
```

Now you get:

```
#m3
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.3810     0.4124   0.924    0.386    
x             0.9053     0.1144   7.914 9.77e-05 ***
zB            0.3547     0.6571   0.540    0.606
```

And:

```
#m4
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.1552     0.4677  -0.332 0.751219    
x             1.0840     0.1410   7.687 0.000254 ***
zB            2.3208     1.2374   1.876 0.109830    
x:zB         -0.3575     0.1994  -1.793 0.123219
```

Now why do you get those odd estimates for B and for the interaction? If you look at R-squared in models *m1* and *m2* you'll notice that R^2 for *m1* is 0.98 and for *m2* is 0.77. That is, you are already explaining almost all the variability with just one variable so when you add another there's not much to add to the fit of the model. Look how the `B` coefficient is not significant in `m3` but it was in `m2`. 
You can interpret the coefficient of `B` in `m3` as the independent effect of `B` in `y` taking into account the effect of `x` in `y`. Since `y` is almost fully explained by `x` the estimated independent effect of `B` is much lower than what you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you @Aghila +1 if I had more rep, I think that makes a lot of sense. However, if you could tell If I were to report the 2 means for `z` and  2 slopes for`z` in your `m4` what they would be? So I know I am subrtactingadiing the effect sizes in the correct way.